# Why do I need the extra binding syntax for this datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

**Background**

If we have a CLR object such as:

```
class Person
{
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

We can create an ObservableCollection, add a little boiler plate code and voila we can bind this to a DataGrid with XAML like:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyOnPersonObject}"\>
```

And the DataGrid knows to take this object and populate each column automatically.

**What happened**

Within a viewmodel, I wanted to create a single column DataGrid with an `ObservableCollection<decimal>`. So I made a public property and bound just like above. What kept happening was I'd get the correct number of rows but no data. Just using ItemsSource wasn't enough.

I finally figured out I needed this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyOnSomething}"> 
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

The DataGrid needed this extra binding code at the column level. Why?

Comment: Thats odd behavior. Just a note, you will *usually* turn AutoColumns off anyways, since the headers aren't very pretty.

Comment: How DataGridTextColumn will know that which property value I suppose to show??? That is why in every Column you must have to provide its binding property. In your case of "<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}"/>",you binded DataGrid's DataContext property to DataGridTextColumn.

Comment: @Phenix_yu AutoGenerateColumns is set to True by default but to answer your question I explicitly set it and got same result. I also got same result with it set to False. Yes PropertyOnSomething is binded to a property of viewmodel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property is responsible for generating the columns for you in the Datagrid automatically.

DataGrid has AutoGenerateColumns set to true by default. If you had used a `ObservableCollection<Person>` it will go through the list of properties of your  `Person` class and generate the items properties - `ReadOnlyCollection<ItemPropertyInfo> itemProperties`. Based on this list it will bind the header and the cells internally.

But in the second case you had used `ObservableCollection<decimal>` which is not an object type but a value type. It does not have any property defined its definition and hence it will not yield any `itemProperties` list. As a result you there wont be any binding done internally and the datagrid will be just empty rows.